# Get total number of month of date using month and yaer

Tags: javascript

I am using JavaScript geting number of total dayes of month date formate (feb-2020). but not geting current result please share valuable idea sir.

**javaScript Cose**

```
dayes = res[0]['task_month'];

 alert(dayes);//work is ok result 'Fab-2020'
```

**i need result**

```
total dayes 29
```

Comment: An easy way would be to set day of month to 1 (2020-02-**01**), then add one month (2020-**03**-01), then remove one day (2020-**02-29**) and then the day of month is the number of days in the month (29)

Comment: sir geting data base feb-2020 . i have need total dayes month only ?

Comment: So your problem comes down to: *how do I get `2020-02-01` (date) from `"feb-2020"` (string)?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code.

```
    var dayes = res[0]['task_month']; // 'Feb-2020'

    function daysInMonth(date){
       var d= new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+1, 0);
       return d.getDate();
    }

    alert(daysInMonth(new Date(dayes)));
```

[Check JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sn5bc1Lj/)

Comment: i am using log before var tab ="";
            var tbody ="";
            var res = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(res);
            global_res = res;

Comment: Will it impact another log ? I don't think so., You just need to plug this code and it will work

Comment: Updated My answer, please check now

Answer (score 3):

Your question is answered here:

[GetDaysInMonth Function](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-date-exercise-3.php)

Comment: var a =  console.log(getDaysInMonth(dayes));
 alert(a); no working sir

Comment: You need to put the function inside your code.
Open the link and copy the function.

Answer (score 0):

To get the total number of days in a given month, use the below code.

```
var getDaysInMonth = function(month,year) {
  // Here January is 1 based
  //Day 0 is the last day in the previous month
 return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
// Here January is 0 based
// return new Date(year, month+1, 0).getDate();
};
console.log(getDaysInMonth(1, 2012));
console.log(getDaysInMonth(2, 2012));
console.log(getDaysInMonth(9, 2012));
console.log(getDaysInMonth(12, 2012));
```

NOTE: Make sure that month and year in this function should be in numbers like getDaysInMonth(1, 2012)) not like getDaysInMonth(Feb, 2012)).

Answer (score 0):

This could work for you.

Based on this [link](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-date-exercise-3.php) I created this example adapted to your specific case, you can try it directly.

```js
var getDaysInMonth = function(input) {
  var month_year = input.split('-');
  var year = parseInt(month_year[1])
  var month = new Date(Date.parse(month_year[0] +" 1, " + year)).getMonth() + 1;
  
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
};

console.log("total dayes " + getDaysInMonth("Jan-2020"));
console.log("total dayes " + getDaysInMonth("Feb-2020"));
console.log("total dayes " + getDaysInMonth("Aug-2020"));
console.log("total dayes " + getDaysInMonth("Feb-2019"));
```